# Custom Landscape/portrait view

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, view, landscape-portrait

I would like to have my buttons arranged a specific way for my portrait view and and different way for my landscape view. I would also like to be able to add things to my landscape view that might now have been in my portrait view. The reasons i know this is possible is obviously, the calculator app that comes with every iphone. When you tilt it sideways into landscape it gives you a whole new set of buttons. Does anyone know how to create a custom portrait view that is loaded when the iphone is right side up and how to create a custom landscape view when the iphone is on its side with different buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try having two separate nib files for each orientation. You can customize the nib based on that.

Comment: Here is a link to the Apple docs for how to do exactly that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW26

Comment: thats what i am currently doing just so i can save both nibs, but i dont know how to switch nib files by rotating the iphone

Comment: ok so its switching now which is great, but my Landscape nib file is not functional (theres virtually no code except wat is being used to rotate it). Do i just need to basically copy and paste the code im using in Portrait view for all of the buttons (cause a lot of it is the same) or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Hi 7KV7.. Thanks for your answer. By which i can identified that its possible. But i am stuck in storyboard. How to achieve the same using stroyboard. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two different view controllers (i.e. NIB files or items in your storyboard).  Call the classes MyViewControllerLandscape and MyViewControllerPortrait.
2. Create a third view controller class programatically.  Call it MyViewController, and make it the parent class of the landscape and portrait controllers.

   This makes it so that you can put all the common code for the two controllers in the parent class and put only the orientation specific code in the other two.
3. Follow the instructions at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW26 to see how to switch between the landscape and portrait viewControllers.